# How to return or look up values from a column if greater than a specific date, without leaving any gaps?

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula, return-value

I'm currently at a loss with excel; imagine the following dates:

```
Date

1-1-2017
3-5-2018
4-7-2018
1-2-2016
6-9-2014
9-9-2018
```

I want to return dates when they are equal to or greater than 1-1-2018 (I know how to use IF statements and datevalue) without leaving any gaps between cells such that:

```
Date        Return

1-1-2017    3-5-2018
3-5-2018    4-7-2018
4-7-2018    9-9-2018
1-2-2016
6-9-2014
9-9-2018
```

I tried fiddling with the formula retrieved from a similar question (https://superuser.com/questions/1169289/return-list-of-all-values-that-match-criteria)
`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$4=$D$1,ROW($B$1:$B$4)-ROW($B$1)+1),ROWS($B$1:$B1))),"")`

However, that specific problem uses two 'lookup' columns, whereas I only have one single column of dates.

Any help would save my life.

Kind regards,

VHes

Comment: If you have 365 you could use the FILTER function?

Answer (score 1):

Using the array formula just remove the reference to B

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$6,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$6>DATEVALUE("01/01/2018"),ROW($B$1:$B$6)-ROW($B$1)+1),ROWS($B$1:$B1))),"")
```

If you have Excel 365 you can use the simpler FILTER formula

```
=FILTER(A1:A6,A1:A6>DATE(2018,1,1))
```

You just type this in one cell and it "spills" down as far as necessary.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by removing the reference to B? I am currently using the following formula in my sheet (adjusted ranges for my sheet)

```=IFERROR(INDEX(Hoofdtab!$I$2:$I$19883;SMALL(IF(Hoofdtab!$I$2:$I$19883>=DATEVALUE("1-1-2018");ROW(Hoofdtab!$I$2:$I$19883)-ROW(Hoofdtab!$I$2)+1);ROWS(Hoofdtab!$I$2:$I$2)));"")```

Where "Hoofdtab" is the tab where I am pulling the dates from. I tried removing the B reference but I end up with the date '1-1-2101' after entering the formula with ctrl+shift+enter. Thanks for your quick response and help!

Kind regards,

VHes

Comment: =FILTER(A1:A6;A1:A6>=43101) is even shorter. 43101 being the excel value for januari 1st 2018

Comment: Not really sure what the problem is. The FILTER approach is better if you have it. And more robust to use DATE rather than DATEVALUE.

Answer (score 1):

Use below formula. You have to format `Column B` as date otherwise it will show just number value of date.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$6)/($A$1:$A$6>=DATE(2018,1,1)),ROW($A1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Your example works perfectly fine on the set of mock dates!

However, when I apply it to my actual data set as follows:

```=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$19882;AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW($A$1:$A$19882)/($A$1:$A$19882>=DATE(2018;1;1));ROW($A1)));"")```

it seems to return dates as per random (including dates that aren't even present in the dataset)

Thanks for your help thus far. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: All are them actual dates in excel or has some text or string? Can you share a sample workbook?

Comment: I think I found the culprit. I'm using company data and there are some sketchy dates in the date list (e.g. 2101 as a year). I think I will need to adjust my date boundaries to: 

```$A$1:$A$19882>=DATE(2018;1;1)```

AND 

```$A$1:$A$19882<=DATE(2021;1;1)```

I'll just need to figure out how to add an AND to the equal or greater than operator now.

Comment: I tried the following but it doesn't seem to yield any results (everything stays blank!)

```=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$19882;AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW($A$1:$A$19882)/(AND($A$1:$A$19882>=DATE(2018;1;1);$A$1:$A$19882<=DATE(2021;1;1)));ROW($A1)));"")```

Any idea on how I should change the double criteria?

Comment: Then use `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$6)/(($A$1:$A$6>=DATE(2018,1,1))*($A$1:$A$6<=DATE(2021,1,1))),ROW($A1))),"")`

Comment: Thanks! This works really well BUT (sorry to keep on bothering you...):

The whole thing goes haywire once I lower the index array one cell (from A1:A19882 to A2:A19883 whilst also adjusting the final row statement from ROW(A1) to ROW(A2). All dollar signs are placed properly as well.

Do you have any idea what might be causing trouble here? I would like to have a column header stating "Date" --> This means that I will have to lower the whole array by one cell.

If needed I can share a sample workbook but I don't know precisely how and what that is.